# Sorting not working for the year "2013"

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I am combining different List into a single one as below:

```
List<Tweet> tweets = new List<Tweet>();

foreach (string TID in TypeIDList)
{
    List<Tweet> lt = new List<Tweet>();
    ......
    tweets = tweets.Concat(lt).OrderByDescending(x => x.TwitTime).ToList();
}

return tweets.OrderByDescending(x => x.TwitTime).ToList();
```

So in the result everything is sorted in descending order except the dates in "2013" that is

`1/1/2013 12:43:15 PM`

So these date are coming at the last instead of at first.

I don't know why it is happening.

Comment: what is `TwitTime`'s type?

Comment: It's impossible to tell how it's sorting if you only show us one data point.

Comment: Is `TwitTime` a `DateTime` ? a `long` ? what? (hint: string would be inadviseable)

Comment: Opss..It's a `string`..Hope this is the mistake. @MarcGravell

Comment: Use a better date format like YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: THis is. Because strings are sorted left to right. SHould be a DateTime or at least use the ISO norm for Dates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing `TwitTime` is a `string`, in which case you would need a format like `"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"` if you wanted to search it without parsing. Simply, alphabetical sorting doesn't work if the most significant part (the year) is at the right-hand-side.

However: a better approach would be: store it in a `DateTime` - that will sort safely.

Comment: Thanks..I just did `OrderByDescending(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.TwitTime))` and it works fine..

Comment: +1, except i would use the ISO form for thadate (yyyy-MM-dd) which is also one SQL Server can always parse.

Comment: @TomTom the main reason I mentioned / is that the OP was using /. Re SQL Server: personally I tend to subscribe to the view that if I'm worrying about what text format of date it will handle, I've already missed an opportunity to parameterise

Comment: Not ALWAYS. THere are some areas where you can not sensibly / well use a datetime and it maeks sense to code a string. For example months (2012-03, no day). Edge cases, but it helps to standardize.

Comment: Don't you mean "sort it without parsing" ?

Answer (score 5):

When sorting `string`s, they are usually compared lexicographically, meaning all strings starting with number `1` will be together:

```
1
10
2
3
...
```

When sorting a date or a time, you could use [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) dates, e.g. 2013-01-01 12:34:23, that happens to sort correctly lexicographically. Many platforms and languages also support correct date comparison function you could use.